# In zendframework2 i am not able to clear session after closing browser

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have been trying hard for clearing session after closing browser. whenever I restart my browser after closing it I tend to have my session intact. which i dont want to happen. I have disabled rememberMe calling also. and have session.cookie_lifetime = 0 in my php.ini.

I am only instantiating this

```
class ClientAuthStorage extends Storage\Session{
public function setRememberMe($rememberMe = 0, $time = 1209600)
{   if ($rememberMe == 1) {
         $this->session->getManager()->rememberMe($time);
     }
}
public function forgetMe()
{
    $this->session->getManager()->forgetMe();
}}
```

and calling it using

```
if ($post['remember_me'] == 1){
    $storage = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Client\Model\ClientAuthStorage');
            $storage->setRememberMe(1);
            $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($storage);
        }}
```

but behavior remains unchanged with or without this code.

After resolving browser exit behavior i also want to have remember me functionality. But first want the default behavior of loosing session upon closure of browser.

Regards